# CryptoAPI and XMLDSIG c, c++, delphi

Tags: c++, c, delphi, cryptoapi

I'm trying to sign a xml document (http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/) with an enveloped signature, I managed to calculate the signed info part but I'm struggling to get a meaningful result from the cryptoapi, unfortunately I have to stick to the crypto api (no external libs, no XmlXec). The signature method is rsa-sha1, the digest method is sha1.
Do you please have any working example of the construction of a xml signature in c, c++ or delphi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an article in the MSDN about XML signatures:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757845(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Am I wrong or the link referes to MSXML 5.0 for Microsoft Office Application?